# How to correctly apply a PERMANOVA to a half-crossed experimental design

Tags: permutation-test, permutation

I'm a biologist and conducted an experiment in which I took analytical samples of aphid infested plants and analyzed them using metabolomics. The plants were chosen based on their Genotype (Motherplant the experimental plant originated from) and Chemotype (Characterized based on the experimental plant's leaf metabolome). Since not every motherplant produces every chemotype, a crossed or fully-factorial experimental design was impossible. In my experiment the following combinations of CT and GT were present:

|  | CT1 | CT2 | CT3 | CT4 | CT5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GT1 | x |  | x |  |  |
| GT2 |  | x | x |  |  |
| GT3 |  |  |  | x | x |
| GT4 |  | x |  | x |  |
| GT5 | x |  |  |  | x |

The numbers of plants across all combinations was equal.

Since metabolomics results in a lot of features (for my samples ~100), the results are often visualized using a NMDS to reduce them down to two dimensions. To report significance values on the experimental factors, we often use PERMANOVA (Adonis, R vegan package) calculated with the same distance measure as the NMDS.

Now my problem is, I don't have a fully crossed design, but also no nested design either. Should I implement the permanova as nested or as crossed?

I calculated two models in R which of course result in very different results:

The first model would be:

```
adonis(only.numeric.transformed~aphidcount*genotype*chemotype, method="kulczynski", permutations = 10000)
```

The second model would be:

```
adonis(only.numeric.transformed~aphidcount*genotype/chemotype, strata=genotype, method="kulczynski", permutations = 10000)
```

Since I dont a have fully crossed design I feel like allowing the algorithm to permute every through combination of Genotype/Chemotype there is, is wrong. However, when trying to define the nestedness, I'm not really sure whether genotype or chemotype should be the strata factor as there is no clear hierarchical structure.